# How can I insert new modules in PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, emacs, pythonpath, ropemacs, rope

I'm installing http://bitbucket.org/agr/ropemacs for my emacs.

In README.txt it say:

Note that rope and ropemacs should be in your `PYTHONPATH` for this
to work.

I check my sys.path python, but there is't any ropemacs there! but I have installed it!
how can I instert ropemacs in PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the included `setup.py`, then the package should be correctly installed and all is well, you can checky by importing it, open a python prompt and type `import ropemacs`.

You probably wouldn't see a directory just for this package, because setuptools normally installs python packages in your `site-packages` directory, which on my machine is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`, for the obvious platforms.

Comment: Aha! all the time I was searching for ropemacs in my PYTHONPATH! Thats because all of the are inside site-packges. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable.  You can add directories to it with a command like

```
PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/rope:/path/to/ropemacs"
```

That can be done from the command line before running emacs, or more permanently in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.  There might be a more convenient emacs-specific way to do it but I am a vim fiend so I can't help you with that.

More info on `PYTHONPATH` here: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/understanding-imports-and-pythonpath

Comment: great tutorial about PYTHONPATH!